# "WeakMap" error when using StyleSheet.create() in React Native Web

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native + Expo app that is running well in iOS and Android. I'm trying to now get it working as a web app, but it fails immediately with the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: WeakMap key 1467 must be an object or an unregistered symbol`

I have traced the error to my `StyleSheet.create()` function, where `1467` is the value of the first key/value pair in the object (in this case `windowWidth`):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    windowWidth: windowWidth,
    windowHeight: windowHeight,
    lightContrastColor: lightContrastColor,
    darkContrastColor: darkContrastColor,
    ...
    })
```

If I comment out the first key/value pair, the thrown error will contain the value of the next one and so on. In the case of `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` these are integers, but for `lightContrastColor` this is a string.

I have absolutely no idea what is going on here, and I haven't been able to find anybody reporting a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to how React Native's StyleSheet.create() function is handling the object keys.

To resolve this issue, use unique object keys

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

let windowWidth="100%";
let windowHeight="100%";
let lightContrastColor="#FFF";
let darkContrastColor="#000";

const index = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.windowWidthStyle,
        styles.windowHeightStyle,
        styles.lightContrastColorStyle,
        styles.darkContrastColorStyle,
      ]}
    >
      <Text>index</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default index;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  windowWidthStyle: {
    width: windowWidth,
  },
  windowHeightStyle: {
    height: windowHeight,
  },
  lightContrastColorStyle: {
    color: lightContrastColor,
  },
  darkContrastColorStyle: {
    color: darkContrastColor,
  },
});
```